# Please synonymize and merge [tag-stats] into [top-users]

Tags: support, meta, retag-request

We had [tag-stats](/questions/tagged/tag-stats) (25) to refer to the original page for Tag Stats. However, with the tag pages being expanded, it was renamed to Top Users. There's a new tag brewing called [top-users](/questions/tagged/top-users) (5) which is used for this.

The mechanisms are identical, save for a few out-dated questions that refer to old functionality of the tag stats. These were out-dated before we even moved from tag stats to top users, however, so I believe it is a safe merge. However, this can't be done by regular users due to the currently exponential relationship between the tag counts.

Comment: You only need to retag 10 of the questions to propose the synonym.

Comment: @Jon I didn't even think of that. Go figure. Maybe I'll work on it myself later today, then. Or you can beat me to the roundhouse. ♪

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manually edited all of the affected posts, and [proposed the synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/top-users/synonyms).

Note: I've already mod-flagged several of the questions as no longer relevant, or to have their mod-only tags changed (mostly [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)).